# sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('multiple' => true, 'model' => 'Test)) - CSS

Tags: php, css, symfony1, doctrine, label

i have widget:

```
'test_list'       => new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('multiple' => true, 'model' => 'test')),
```

this return in html:

```
<li>
<input id="aaa_test_list_3" type="checkbox" value="3" name="aaa[test_list][]">
<label for="aaa_test_list_3">Name</label>
</li>
```

etc

how can i this edit? i would like delete **label** (where i can this change?) or add class for this.
In css i have set template for label, but i would like other template for label in this list. 
i would like create for example:

```
li label {
 // somehow clear inheritance
}
```

how can i make this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of echoing the entire form at once, or calling renderRow() for each element, you can use the render(), renderLabel(), renderHelp() and renderError() methods, which will mean you can get much more control over the HTML.

For more info, see here:

http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/10#chapter_10_sub_the_form_template

(especially the grey box a couple of paragraphs down from there)

Comment: it i know. i would like edit template from  sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice . there arent in templates.